# creating C++ program that runs on most of PCs

Tags: c++, .net, frameworks

I have a project that requires writing a code for small executable file. I used visual C++ express 2010 IDE to create this file. After I finished writing the code, I tried to copy it to a couple of different PCs. It gives me an error message every time I clicking on this file to execute it. The message states that I have to install (.NET framework).  I watched a couple videos on YouTube explaining how overcome this problem by changing the runtime library from multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) to multi-threaded Debug (/Mtd). However; the IDE can’t debug the C++ code because when I create my project by using CLR template! 
Is there any way to solve this problem? Can I create a similar program that not requires any further downloading once I using on different PC?

Is learning a different language like JAVA or C# will help creating small programs (like my program) that run on most Window platform machine?

Comment: Create a pure C++ program, not using the .NET framework?

Comment: Dude i think you are learning C/C++, if so, go for Linux use GCC as your compiler and VI as editor, its better for initial learning then you can move toward fancy world of .net. If you want to stick with windows dont use Microsoft extension! With this you dont need .Net framework

Comment: If you're linking the debug libraries computers w/o the debug runtime won't run it correctly. Try `/Mt` instead of `/Mtd`

Answer (score 7):

Just use Qt - it runs on Windows, Linux, MacOS, support for Android and iOS is scheduled for this year, plus it supports embedded platforms and some of the more obscure mobile platforms. Also, support for Windows RT was just kickstarted.  A complete library with tons of functionality, good documentation and lots of educational resources. It provides tons of tools, from implicitly shared containers through threading, signals and slots, 2D and 3D graphics, widgets, multimedia, sensors... and whatnot...

You can even develop commercial applications under the LGPL license.

Also comes with a pretty good IDE - Qt Creator.

You can develop standard C++ applications or use QML, which is a JavaScript like language for markup and scripting, which is used to build applications from C++ implemented components. You can also extend QML. It is much faster to develop with QML and you still get the advantages of platform native binary under the hood.

Note that you will still need to either ship a few DLLs with your application. Unless of course you use a static build, which requires you to either have your application open source, or purchase a commercial license... which doesn't come cheap...

But still, a few MB of DLLs are far better than the entire .NET framework. A static build will produce executables about 8-9 MB with no external dependencies.

Comment: Obviously, the OP is a beginner. Thus, he/she should not start with any fancy GUI programming like Qt. In addition, for learning purposes are IDEs like Qt Creator (and also Visual Studio) rather impedimental.

Comment: @Matthias - you can just as well use Qt for trivial console applications. Also, using creator, typing a few lines of code and hitting the RUN button is far simple than writing in some lame text editor and compiling/linking manually...

Comment: @ddriver That's a false statement. You can use Qt creator for trivial console application, not the Qt framework. It may be you who is lame, not the text editor.

Comment: @user1095108 - oh yeah, you can't use QTextStream instead of std::cout? You cannot use QMap instead of std::map? And easy with the name calling...

Comment: @ddriver Containers nor streams have anything to do with console application programming per se.

Comment: @user1095108 - troll much? You still haven't explained how exactly the Qt framework can't be used for trivial console applications?

Comment: @ddriver the event loop is an integral part of every Qt application. To use the facilities Qt provides, one needs to instantiate Q*Application and enter the event loop. By default, the event loop will not exit unless every window of the application is closed, or a custom handler is written. For this reason a Qt application cannot be called trivial or console.

Comment: @user1095108 - last time I checked it was possible to use the Qt framework without a QApplication. But you seem to be out on a mission, so by all means, keep trolling. I'm out!

Comment: @ddriver: If you only want to make "trivial console applications", what then is the sense in using it? In addition: I don't want to judge, whether QtC editor is less 'lame' than any other editor, but exactly the "press a button" approach often turns into an obstacle to understand what is going on.

Comment: Because it will be easier to migrate from a trivial application to a production application later on. What point of learning STL when it provides only core facilities, when you can learn the Qt core functionality and later on use that knowledge in the rest of the framework that relies on it.

Answer (score 3):

Stick with the C++ standard, avoid Microsoft extensions (managed code), and call only POSIX functions of your OS, then you should be able to write portable programs.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have created a `Managed C++ Project`. Instead create an empty `Win32 C++ project` and then add in your .cpp/.h files. This will limit you to the default libraries available on all PCs with the C++ runtime. If you want to remove that dependency too then statically compile in the runtime using the `/MT` option. Details @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.71).aspx

As you move ahead you would need to be conscious of what libraries you take dependencies on and what versions of the OS are those libraries available on or if you need to package them with your bits.

Answer (score 0):

Both Java and C# will help making portable programs. Usually, people will have to install runtime environments for executables written in these two languages, however. These days, C++ is more portable than ever. You can easily run C++ executables in your browser:

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten

http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/

This makes many of the reasons why Java and C# came about irrelevant.

Open standards like OpenGL also make portable GUI programming easier than ever. Try Qt, if you want to write a simple GUI in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Note: **It is possible to run C++ program in any computer without installing anything  if you haven't use .NET framework**. In your case,  there can be two reasons to trigger error in target computer.

1. New computer doesn't have required run-time assembles.
2. New computer doesn't have required .NET framework installed.

..........................................

**So what to do:**

1. Before start your program you have to design weather are you going to use .NET framework support or not. If you use .NET framework when you develop your program, then you much install same or higher .NET framework in target computer.
2. If you no need to use .NET component then your target computer should only containing run-time assemblies. 
   How to get rid of .net framework

   - right click on the project in solution -> properties -> General -> Common language run time support -> select "No common language run time support".

..........................................

Then what you need is only relevant run-time assemblies be in target computer.

**How can run-time assemblies be in new computer:**

There are two ways:

1. Install suitable C++ disputable environment in target computer(if you use VS2008 SP1, C++ RD package should be [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582). Please consider the solution build architecture also (32 bit/64 bit) before download ).
2. Deploy run-time assemblies with your solution package. (I like this because user no need to install any third party components)

..........................................

**How Deploy assemblies with my project:**

1. for this your all DLL, LIB, EXE should use same run time version.(if not, you face troubling to redirect assemblies by 'manifest' files ).
2. How to check the run-time version.
   open DLL,EXE by visual studio (open->file) -> expand RT_MANIFEST-> double click the file under it ->then assembly dependency details will open. -> copy the data in right column and paste to note pad.

You will see this kind of line there. and ther is the version run-time assemblies your specific DLL or EXE use.

```
assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86".....
```

After identifying the version of run-time assemblies follow [this](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/03/deploying-visual-c-runtime-files-as-private-assemblies/) tutorial and try to run in fresh installed computer.

**At last:** If you think this bla.. bla.. is so complex and your program is very simple, then you can consider about "run time assemblies statically linking" (try Google). But personally I don't like this method.

good luck!